# Ensure CSP is effective against XSS attacks in wordpress how solve?

Tags: wordpress, security, content-security-policy

At first, I am not a developer, I just know how to work with WordPress and some `HTML` and `CSS`, so when I was testing my website in web dev and I saw this message:

> Ensure CSP is effective against XSS attacks: No CSP found in
> enforcement mode

I want your help to solve this problem in Wordpress, how can I solve it?

you can see the screenshot of the problem in:
[image]

Comment: I think this question would be more suited for [wordpress.stackexchange.com](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/). There are some plugins that allow you to set these header the one that I use to do this [defender](https://wpmudev.com/project/wp-defender/) by WPMUDEV. there may be free solutions too

Answer (score 0):

Few questions :

- what is a XSS attack and how does it work ? https://portswigger.net/web-security/cross-site-scripting
- What is CSP and how to use it ? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP

Visite this website, you should find all what you need : https://web.dev/strict-csp/

I read you question too quickly but all links above can still be useful.
Try this website it will give you some informations about your CSP : https://cspscanner.com/